# how to make unity2d point-and-click movement smooth?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouseevent, game-physics

I have a rectangle player sprite with a Box Collider 2D and a Rigidbody2D attached. I also have a script for point-and-click movement attached to the player object (i.e. player moves to mouse click position). However as soon as the player character hits a collider, it starts to jitter rather than just fully stop. I don't know a lot about Unity physics other than what I've picked up in a few tutorials, so I'll include as much relevant information as I can.

The Rigidbody 2D component has all forces set to 0, except for mass being 0.0001. The body type is dynamic, and collision detection is set to continuous. My movement script looks like this, got it straight from a tutorial:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1;
    private Vector3 target;

    void Start()
    {
        target = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            target.z = transform.position.z;
        }
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Is there an easier way to implement smooth point-and-click movement?

Comment: youd need to check you can move forward with a raycast to stop the jitter as  you are basically headbutting everything repeatedly

Comment: This worked, thank you! For anyone having the same problem: Try and change the Update() method to FixedUpdate() as well.